# Which JSF event handler is to use for content-dependent changes on view?

Tags: jsf, event-handling, jsf-2

I have a h:form with inputs field that are marked mandatory. I'd like to register an event handler that gets to act upon checking whether or not the 'mandatory' criteria has been satisfied (if yes: no changes, if no: color the background of the component red).

I have yet to find out, which event handler is made for this use-case. I have tried out javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent, which should do the job if this were a validation issue. As far as I know the JSF lifecycle, validation is never called when a mandatory field does not meet its criteria (thus re-rendering the view 'immediate'ly).

Thanks for finding out the right choice!

Comment: I am not clear with your requirement but itcan be done with client side validations (javascript )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'd like to register an event handler that gets to act upon checking whether or not the 'mandatory' criteria has been satisfied (if yes: no changes, if no: color the background of the component red).*

Is it also okay to just check if the component is valid, regardless of the conversion/validation used?

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" required="true" 
    styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'none' : 'error'}" />
```

*(the EL `#{component}` reference inside an input component refers to an [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) instance of the component itself, this class has in turn an [`isValid()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) method, that's why it works that way)*

And define CSS like follows

```css
input.error {
    background: #fee;
}
```

If not, or if you want a more generic solution, (or if you're using JSF 1.x which doesn't support `#{component}`), then you can also consider to use a [`PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html). You can find an example in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html).

Comment: Certainly my high hopes in an answer from you have not been in vain. Your proposed solution solved the problem immediately and - even better - made all the workarounds I had to do in the backing-bean obsolete. Many thanks to you!